# Prove that if $x, y, z ∈ \Bbb R^k $, then $|x| + |y| + |z| = |x + y − z| + |x − y + z| + | − x + y + z|.$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Prove that if $x, y, z ∈ \Bbb R^k$ , then $$|x| + |y| + |z| ≤ |x + y − z| + |x − y + z| + | − x + y + z|.$$

I'm studying for an upcoming midterm and this was a practice problem with no available solution. 
I know that it is related to the properties of Euclidean spaces and the triangle inequality, but because there are three variables I'm not sure how to go about this.

I tried:
$|x| + |y| + |z| ≥ |x+y+z| $,

$|x+y+z|^2 = (x+y+z)(x+y+z)^c$

But I'm not sure if that is how I'm supposed to go about this proof.

Answer (score 3):

This is false as stated. Let ${\bf y} = {\bf z} = {\bf 0}$, and ${\bf x} \neq {\bf 0}$. The equality boils down to $\|{\bf x}\| = 3\|{\bf x}\|$, which is false.

Answer (score 2):

Your title does not match the statement in your prompt, i.e.,

> Prove that if $x, y, z ∈ \Bbb R^k$ , then $$|x| + |y| + |z| \color{red}{≤} |x + y − z| + |x − y + z| + | − x + y + z|.$$

To prove this statement, write

$$x = \frac{2x}{2} = \frac{(x + y-z) + (x - y + z)}{2},$$

By the triangle inequality,

$$|x| \le \frac{1}{2}(|x + y - z| + |x - y + z|).\tag{1}$$

We also have

$$y = \frac{(x + y - z) + (-x + y + z)}{2}, \quad z = \frac{(x - y + z) + (-x + y + z)}{2}.$$

So then

$$|y| \le \frac{1}{2}(|x + y - z| + |-x + y + z|).\tag{2}$$

and

$$|z| \le \frac{1}{2}(|x - y + z| + |-x + y + z|).\tag{3}$$

The result is obtained by adding inequalities $(1)$, $(2)$, and $(3)$ together.